# How read line by line txt file in odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

```
my_file = fields.Binary(string='My txt file')

@api.one
def read_file(self):

    filename = self.my_file.decode('base64')
    print(filename)
```

Print return all data in file!

```
1  TEST  100 

2  TEST2  200 

3  TEST3  300 

4  TEST4  400
```

I want get row 1 eg. (`'number':1`,`'name':TEST`,`'price':100`)

Comment: Please check this may be help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example:

```
lines = filename.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    print(str(line.split()))
```